# Will a tight long-lasting loop in a Thread slow down the other Threads substantially?

Tags: java, multithreading

My basic question here is if an intense loop (not sure the technical term? standard loop? - but a loop that doesn't yield anything, no Thread.sleep() is being called - is just fine and dandy as far as the other threads are concerned.

I tried an example, and it seems to work - although it spits out so much text that it's hard to know exactly what is doing. But the main thing I was looking out for was if there were any delays, and there seemed not to be.

So I would just like confirmation that code like this, without calling any Thread.Sleep() is fine and won't cause unnecessary delays to the other threads of the java application.

```
public class TestThreadStability implements Runnable {

private final String name;

public TestThreadStability(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new TestThreadStability("a")).start();
    new Thread(new TestThreadStability("b")).start();
    new Thread(new TestThreadStability("c")).start();
    new Thread(new TestThreadStability("d")).start();
    new Thread(new TestThreadStability("e")).start();
    new Thread(new TestThreadStability("f")).start();
    new Thread(new TestThreadStability("g")).start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
            while (true) {
                // this is ok? it doesn't adversely affect the other threads much?
            }
        else System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: as a side note, is the inner "while (true)" in the byte code or does it get optimized out as it doesn't really do much useful?

Comment: btw. in the real code, the purpose of the loop is to check a flag on another thread - but I don't want to sleep the thread, since I want it to act as soon as the flag is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will cause delays if you are running the program in a single core.

Why you don't you notice it? threads are scheduled in a round-robin basis, which means that if there are 4 threads running at full speed, each get 25%.

If you have 1 full-speed thread, and 3 other very-little-work threads, the full-speed thread will work most of the time, but will be forced to yield to allow the other threads to do their work.

Comment: but actually this code will never be run on a single core machine ever. It will be run on i7 in production and i5 laptop (dual core) for development.

Comment: oh, is that a jvm argument?

Comment: @Regarding your first comment, you should put a bigger delay. But in your case it doesn't matter, because the thread will be forced to yield anyways. The problem here, is that you should not rely on polling a flag, you should use a event-driven design with listeners/futures/async/callbacks.

Comment: ok I will rework my code to use a callback. don't really know what a future is but I'll read up on that.

Comment: **Edit** on my previous comment: it seems I was wrong on this, Java uses native threads, so they will run on different cores if available. Still, it is a bad design to poll a flag like that, consider using some kins of events instead.

Comment: @ycomp, Re "So maybe I should put a Thread.sleep()?"  No.  If your code calls `Thread.sleep()`, then either you are re-inventing some wheel  (e.g., ScheduledExecutorService or javax.swing.Timer), or you probably are making a mistake.  If you have normal-priority threads doing CPU-bound computation, the only thing that `Thread.sleep()` will do is make the computation take longer. You would need `Thread.yield()` calls in a _cooperative multitasking_ environment, but you'd already know that by now if it was true.  (I've never even heard of a cooperative multitasking _Java_ environment.)

Comment: I do use `Thread.Sleep()` in parts of my code also to prevent spamming `API` servers - but I can't think of how to else to do that without `Thread.Sleep()` - this is unrelated to the main question, it's just a question about not using `Thread.Sleep()` in code

Comment: @ycomp You could use Long-Polling for example, or WebSockets. Any event-based form of communication will be better than regular polling, but that's a whole other question. The usage of `Thread.sleep()` is not bad in itself, the problem is in what you use it for.